# usar method post para agregar un registro

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Segun lei cada method tiene su objetivo:

> post para insertar registros,
>
> get para obtener/mostrar registros,
>
> put para modificar registros,
>
> delete para eliminar registros

hice el siguiente codigo, que agrega un nuevo libro a la bd entonces deberia usar el method post, pero lo hice con el method get, quiero convertirlo a method post, como hacerlo?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}/{name}/{author}/{price}")
    public Book addBook(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String author,
            @PathVariable long price) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(id);
        book.setName(name);
        book.setAuthor(author);
        book.setPrice(price);
        bookService.saveBook(book);
        return book;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo agrega el método HTTP requerido en la anotación `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping` a través del elemento **`method`**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}/{name}/{author}/{price}",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Book addBook(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String author,
            @PathVariable long price) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(id);
    book.setName(name);
    book.setAuthor(author);
    book.setPrice(price);
    bookService.saveBook(book);
    return book;
}
```

Opcionalmente puedes enviar los datos en el cuerpo de la petición y no en la URL:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Book addBook(
            @RequestParam(name = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int id,
            @RequestParam(name = "name", required = true) String name,
            @RequestParam(name = "author", required = true) String author,
            @RequestParam(name = "price", required = true) long price) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(id);
    book.setName(name);
    book.setAuthor(author);
    book.setPrice(price);
    bookService.saveBook(book);
    return book;
}
```

Desde la versión 4.3 de Spring es posible utilizar la anotación `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping`, la cual actua como un atajo de `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public Book addBook(
            @RequestParam(name = "id", required = false, defaultValue = "0") int id,
            @RequestParam(name = "name", required = true) String name,
            @RequestParam(name = "author", required = true) String author,
            @RequestParam(name = "price", required = true) long price) {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(id);
    book.setName(name);
    book.setAuthor(author);
    book.setPrice(price);
    bookService.saveBook(book);
    return book;
}
```

Otro anotaciones que son atajos:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping
```

Comment: agrego registros desde la url, como hago desde el cuerpo de la peticion?

Comment: donde pongo las anotaciones? org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping... deleteMapping, getMapping.. etc

Comment: Si estás usando Spring 4.3, irían en cada método correspondiente. [Aquí](http://javasampleapproach.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-framework-4-3-new-feature-requestmapping-getmapping-postmapping-putmapping-deletemapping) puede ver un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

> POST para insertar registros,
>
> GET para obtener/mostrar registros,
>
> PUT para modificar registros,
>
> DELETE para eliminar registros

Es correcto, sin embargo para GET según el protocolo HTTP(que es en el que se basa REST) su entrada de datos es a través de parámetros como en tu método GET, pero en POST es por medio de un body:

Ejemplo:

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String name,
    private String author,
    private long price

//Setters and Getters
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public EntityResponse addBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
    bookService.saveBook(book);
    return new ResponseEntity(book, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

para crear un registro tambien ser resuelve con 201 en vez de 200, en el status HTTP